# How to link a table row to another frame?

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jQuery and want to link the table row to another target frame.

Table row:

```
<tr data-href="home.html" target="content"><td><h3><center>Home</h3></td></tr>
```

Using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("tr").on({
        click: function() {
            window.location = $(this).data("href");
            $(this).css("background-color","blue");
        }
    });
});
```

But it opens the link in the same frame.

Answer (score 0):

When setting the `window.location` property, it changes the location of the current window rather than any specific frame.

Assuming you have an `<iframe>` with the `name` attribute set to "content", you'll need to change your `click` function to:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("tr").on({
    click: function() {
      $("iframe[name='content']").attr("src", $(this).data("href"));
      $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr data-href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="content">
    <td>
      <h3>
        <center>Home</centre>
      </h3>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<iframe name="content"></iframe>
```